# A script that makes anchor min max positioned at Gameobject ui corners?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner in unity3d and i am struggling to make the Ui anchor min max same position as the Button position when moved, my goal is try to achieve like the pictures below.

[image]

[image]

as you can see when the button moves the anchors min max does not following with it, in what way should i solve this using C#? at the moment i move my button with the follow script:

```
    public GameObject SaleButtonPrefab;

    //To loop all the list
    for(int i = 0; i < playerList.Count; i++)
    {

        //Instantiate the button prefab and make a parent
        GameObject nu = Instantiate(SaleButtonPrefab) as GameObject;
        nu.transform.SetParent(ParentButton.transform, false);

        //To set the position
        nu.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, (i*-301) - 0);

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured it out, and to accomplish my goal i modify some of the scripts i have found useful in the internet. This is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GUITest : MonoBehaviour 
{

    private RectTransform t;
    private RectTransform pt;

    void Start()
    {
        t = gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        pt = gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().parent as RectTransform;

        if(t == null || pt == null) return;

        Vector2 newAnchorsMin = new Vector2(t.anchorMin.x + t.offsetMin.x / pt.rect.width,
                                         t.anchorMin.y + t.offsetMin.y / pt.rect.height);
        Vector2 newAnchorsMax = new Vector2(t.anchorMax.x + t.offsetMax.x / pt.rect.width,
                                         t.anchorMax.y + t.offsetMax.y / pt.rect.height);

        t.anchorMin = newAnchorsMin;
        t.anchorMax = newAnchorsMax;
        t.offsetMin = t.offsetMax = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
}
```

To make this work i save this script as C#, after that i attach it to any UI object and when you run your unity game the UI anchor will automatically resize itself around the UI object. i find this useful when instantiating a prefab and looping it because you cant really change the anchors.

Source: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/782478/unity-46-beta-anchor-snap-to-button-new-ui-system.html